# Why email validation in Vue for input doesn't work if id div is removed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am very new to Vue.js,  I want to learn in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/MmpBjV) (not mine) why if we remove the div with id="app" fails to render email validator input field.

```
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div :class="['input-group', isEmailValid()]">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></span>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" v-model="email" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to sue this email validator input field in my single file component i.e. (.vue), if I add attribute `el: '#app'` still I get not able to find element app in the console. even if I keep the `div` with `id="app"`

I tried this:

```
  <div :class="['input-group', isEmailValid()]"  id="app>
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></span>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" v-model="email" />
  </div>
```

to fit it in my single file component but it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm a bit confused, and maybe its more a language barrier - but the codepen seems to be working correctly.  What isn't working as expected?  If you remove the `div#app` element, the app has nowhere to mount - is that your question?

Comment: well the codepen isn't mine, I was trying to learn..

Comment: please reproduce your issue here https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Answer (score 1):

It's because Vue doesn't know where to mount.

see `new Vue({ el: '#app'` in the script? If you want to change the id, change both the div id and the `el` value. If you remove it, you'll need to find another way to mount.

Comment: In my single file component, `.vue` file before the data I added `el:”tapp”` and also set the `<div id=“tapp”` but in console I got error saying cannot find element ‘tapp’

Comment: if you set the `id="tapp"` then you need to change `el:"tapp"` to -> `el:"#tapp"`

Comment: Also, if you're using a `.vue` sfc, you do not do this. You rely on defining components and using those within your mounted application (`main.js` usually). You cannot reproduce this setup in a codepen. If you're still having issues, you will need to either clarify your question, create a new on, or spend some time reading the vue docs, they are some of the best I've seen for a front-end js.

Comment: thank you @Daniel , I jumped into some help from an example tutorial to quickly get my head around : so I made this vue component: https://frontstuff.io/build-your-first-vue-js-component but in `main.js` the author specify `el:"#app"` but does not uses in the `Rating.vue` so how does this work ?

Comment: she uses `components: { Rating }`, and `import Rating from './components/Rating'` this enables one to use the component then in the template: `template: '<Rating/>'`

Comment: So in that case ‘el:”#app”` is not getting used, but I tried renaming this `”app”` to something else and I get error in console element app not found even when I don’t see it any of the components!

Comment: it *is* getting used, see `el: '#app',` in main js